# Xamarin Form setter FontFamily reference custom font in same file theme

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, coding-style

I am trying to reference a font in a style from my default theme. But I find myself with this error without finding a solution for the moment ...

DefaultTheme.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="EntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-300}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-900}"/>
    <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-400}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Montserrat-Regular}"/>
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-White}"/>
</Style>

<OnPlatform x:Key="Montserrat-Regular" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <OnPlatform.Platforms>
        <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Regular" />
        <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
    </OnPlatform.Platforms>
</OnPlatform>
```

This is the error I get:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException : Position 43:39 StaticResource not found for key Montserrat-Regular

Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images.  Read [ask] for guidance on do's and don't of asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It loads the resources in the first in first out order.

Since you have defined the font resource later, at the time of setting `EntryStyle` properties its not found.

Move the Montserrat-Regular above `EntryStyle` you should be good to go.

```xml
<!-- 1st -->
<OnPlatform x:Key="Montserrat-Regular" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <OnPlatform.Platforms>
        <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Regular" />
        <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
    </OnPlatform.Platforms>
</OnPlatform>
<!-- 2nd -->
<Style x:Key="EntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-300}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-900}"/>
    <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-400}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Montserrat-Regular}"/>
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-White}"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31872/application-resources-staticresource-not-found-for-key), your `DefaultTheme` is a global style, so you need to use a DynamicResource for that.

The same Style defined in the Page's Resources section, works successfully.

So technically, just change that line to
`<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource Montserrat-Regular}"/>`